# Why does taking a function pointer to `operator new` compile in C++14, but not in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, operator-overloading, auto

Consider the following code ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/4vvaaozqr)):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    auto foo = operator new;
    void* mem = foo(1);
    printf("%p", mem);
}
```

This code compiles on GCC, Clang, and MSVC with the C++ version set to C++ 14, but it fails to compile when using C++ 17 or later. On GCC, it fails with the following error:

```
error: unable to deduce 'auto' from 'operator new'
```

I expected the code to either compile or not compile in both versions. What changed in C++ 17 that makes it so that the type of `operator new` can no longer be deduced?

Comment: In C++14, there was only one `operator new` function.  In C++17, there are two `operator new` functions — the compiler doesn't know which one you want.

Comment: `operator new` is not an [addressable library function](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6) so this program has unspecified behaviour and is possibly ill-formed in any C++ standard.

Comment: Just use a lambda function, removes all ambiguity.

Comment: @Vince Great first question on SO! Most new C++ contributors tends to ask silly questions that got massively downvoted, but this one is interesting even for seasoned C++ programmers like me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What changed in C++ 17 that makes it so that the type of operator new can no longer be deduced?

This is [P0035R4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html)<sup>1</sup>. It introduces in C++17 a new (pun intended) `operator new` to allow *dynamic memory allocation for over-aligned data*.

You can find on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) the *two* following operators:

```
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al );
```

This makes `auto foo = operator new` ambiguous as it could match both operators.

As user [*n. m. will see y'all on Reddit*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806) commented:

> `operator new` is not an [addressable library function](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6) so this program has unspecified behaviour and is possibly ill-formed in any C++ standard.

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> #### Problem statement
>
> To codify widespread existing practice, C++11 added the ability to specify increased alignment (a.k.a. over-alignment) for class types. Unfortunately (but also consistently with existing practice), C++11 did not specify any mechanism by which over-aligned data can be dynamically allocated correctly (i.e. respecting the alignment of the data). For example:
>
> ```
> class alignas(16) float4 {
>   float f[4];
> };
> float4 *p = new float4[1000];
> ```
>
> In this example, not only is an implementation of C++ not required to allocate properly-aligned memory for the array, for practical purposes it is very nearly required to do the allocation incorrectly. In any event, it is certainly required to perform the allocation by a process that does not take the specified alignment value into account.
>
> This represents a hole in the support for alignment in the language, which really needs to be filled.